SLDS Validator Error in VS Code
I am getting this error in VS Code with Salesforce Extensions for VS Code installed.
This looks like a proxy error, Where do i configure proxy for this?
Has anyone faced this error and resolved it?
Client SLDS Validator: connection to server is erroring.
write ECONNRESET
Shutting down server.


Have you had a look into the slds-extension.log ?
